# How to use a struc in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

so ive been doing c++ for a little while now but im wondering how to use a struct in a class, lets say i was making a FPS game i created a basic structure for a gun:

```
struct gun
{
  int damage;
  string name;
  int number_of_bullets;
};
```

and i created a class for a enemy like this:

```
class enemy
{
  const int max_health = 100;
  int health;
  int damage;
  gun mgun;
};
```

when i compile the program i get a error that sais: 'gun' does not name type.
what am i doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Is the code to declare the `struct` before the code that uses it? In C++ the order of declarations matter.

Comment: (1) You forgot the semicolon at the end of the `gun` definition. (2) You need to make sure that `gun` is defined *before* `enemy`. Impossible to tell from the code you've posted if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you, i realized i put the structure after the gun class :3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you have to define "gun" before your class.
2) put a semicolon at end of struct "gun"

```
struct gun
{
    int damage;
    string name;
    int number_of_bullets;
};
```

3)in your class , the "const int max health = ...." is wrong put an '_' between "max" & "health" or something else.